# org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner Scan URL, caught java.io.IOException: Could not list directory

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, ioexception

I run JBoss 4.2.3 GA on a production server, it's the second time in a few days that the server crashes and the log file shows these messages:

> 2014-04-16 09:55:07,398 WARN  [org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner] Scan URL, caught java.io.IOException: Could not list directory '/usr/local/jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy', reason unknown
>
> 2014-04-16 09:55:12,403 WARN  [org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner] Scan URL, caught java.io.IOException: Could not list directory '/usr/local/jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy', reason unknown
>
> 2014-04-16 09:55:17,407 WARN  [org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner] Scan URL, caught java.io.IOException: Could not list directory '/usr/local/jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/deploy', reason unknown

Of course the deploy directory is still there, no problems at the O/S level.

Any suggestion about the direction in which to investigate the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems be a bug in JBoss AS (https://community.jboss.org/message/259438) - but that should be fixed in 4.2.3 I guess. Are you sure that the permissions are correct, i.e can the user running JBoss actually access the deploy folder? Never happened before? Could be that you're running out of file descriptors.

Comment: Hello Peter, thank you for your answer. The error never happened in years and it happened two times in the last few days. Of course the permissions are correct, because a simple JBoss restart solves the problem. Do you think that increasing the jboss user nofile limits could solve the problem?

Comment: It could definitely help. Whats the current limit? You could try `lsof` and see how many descriptors that are used..

Comment: The current limit is 1024. The stange thing is that `lsof -p <pid of jboss jvm> | wc -l` returns 1314, which is over, but at this time the server seems stable...

Comment: There are HARDLIMITS and SOFTLIMITS so it might be ok. I would increase it just to be sure, 1024 is quite low.

Comment: OK, done. Now `ulimit -a` returns 2048 in a jboss user shell. How can I apply the new limit to the current jboss java process? Is a shutdown and restart enough? Thank you!

Comment: Restart is probably for the best. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Peter for the assistance. I'm crossing my fingers...